# VBA catch the "calculate sheet (shift+f9)" and "calculate workbook" events

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know if this is trivial or actually hacky to do : is it possible to catch the "calculate sheet (shift+f9)" and "calculate workbook" events in VBA ?

I want to hide some processes that manipulate a few thousands lines, to just display some key values. I am calculating a distribution, the thousands lines, and want to just output the percentiles and some stats, as well as the graph instead of all these lines. At the moment I was thinking of a classic macro button, but my users are keener on the F9 way of life..

Do you think I'm pointing towards something interesting with what I suggest in the title ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OnKey command allows you to disable any key or key combination or make that key do something different.

This macro will be executed automatically when the workbook containing it is opened.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

  Application.OnKey "{F9}", "HandleF9"
  Application.OnKey "^{F9}", "HandleCtrlF9"
  Application.OnKey "+{F9}", "HandleShiftF9"

End Sub
```

The following routines will be executed instead of Calculate.

```
Sub HandleF9()
  Debug.Print "F9 clicked"
End Sub
Sub HandleCtrlF9()
  Debug.Print "Ctrl+F9 clicked"
End Sub
Sub HandleShiftF9()
  Debug.Print "Shift+F9 clicked"
End Sub
```

See OnKey help for more information.

Comment: I have never placed my code anywhere other than a module.  I know there are other choices for some code but I cannot help you with those choices.  To test my code, I created a workbook with two sheets each with some formula.  I disabled automatic calculation so I could use F9 and Shift+F9 when I wished.  I opened the VB editor and inserted a module.  I entered the code above.  "Auto_Open" is a keyword; Excel will automatically execute a macro with this name when a workbook is opened (subject to macros being allowed).  You might wish to make this code a user choice.

Comment: Debug.Print outputs to the immediate window.  Within the VB Editor, click Ctrl+G to display/undisplay the immediate window.

Comment: Sorry @jerome G your comments have disppeared from my screen.  My apologies if I deleted them.  I hope my answers make sense without the questions.