# Excel VBA : How to override Sheet Calculation via its associated event?

Tags: excel, vba

in the Worksheet_Calculate event of my sheet (triggered on SHIFT+F9), I need to override the calculation process. More precisely, I want to disable the default sheet calculation to replace that by some custom calculation. I need to calculate some things, then load some things in between, then compute some other cells, etc... I don't want Excel trying to calculate everything because 1. that takes a while 2. it is useless in my process

Is this possible ?

Comment: How does this question differ from your question of 30 November [VBA catch the “calculate sheet (shift+f9)” and “calculate workbook” events](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8327329/973283)?

Comment: That former question was about finding out about events, this is about overriding Excel calculation. By default Excel still does a complete calculation of everything and in this case it is deadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to switch to Manual Calculation mode in the Worksheet_Calculate event, (Application.Calculation=xlManual) do your custom calculation etc, then switch back to automatic calculation (Application.Calculation=xlAutomatic). You would also need to set Application.EnableEvents to false at the start and then back to true at the end to avoid repeated calls to Worksheet_Calculate

Comment: That works great ! May I just mention for future users who'll find that useful, add an error label in which you make sure to reenable calculation. Otherwise, in case of exception, your event won't get triggered anymore.